# sort histogram columns order with seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I wanted to analyze our team's development source code quality so i made a histogram indicating the severity of program's bugs. I want to organize the order of columns by the severity (Low -> High or reverse)

I have a table like this:

[image]

Using seaborn i have this histogram

```
sns.displot(data = incidents, x = 'Severity', order = )
```

[image]

Using some ugly code + barplot i have this. But i wonder is there any better way.

```
severity = pd.DataFrame(incidents[].value_counts().sort_index())
severity.plot(y = 'severity', kind = 'bar')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the order of categorical values, you can use pandas Categorical to set the order to what you like it to be and sort it before plotting. Below example should do this for you...

```
incidents.Severity = pd.Categorical(values=incidents.Severity, categories=['Critical', 'High', 'Medium', 'Low']) ## Set the order for the column as you want
incidents.sort_values(['Severity'], inplace=True) ## Sort the column
sns.displot(data = incidents, x = 'Severity')  ## and plot
```

**Plot**

[image]